# How to make a list where some elements share the same children?

Tags: html, jquery, r, shiny

How to make a list where some elements share the same children.

I am making an app using Shiny R to show a flowchart.
I didn't find a library that did what I was looking for, so I found [jOrgChart](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart) a plugin that allows you to render structures with nested elements in an easy-to-read tree structure just the way I need it.
However within my flowchart some nodes have common childrens.
My question is, how can I generate nested lists with common childrens?, below I attach a diagram of what I am looking for.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you

***If you know a way to make interactive flowcharts in Shiny R easier, I'm open to suggestions.***

```
|-node1
| |-node1.1
|   |-node1.1.1
|-node2
| |-node2.1
            |-node2.(1/2).1
| |-node2.2
|-node3
| |-node3.1
            |
| |-node3.2 |-node3.(1/2/3).1
            |
| |-node3.2
```

Comment: I believe your question is unanswerable because list elements, by definition, have at most one parent: [If the same value occurs multiple times, each occurrence is considered a distinct item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)).  I think you need a different underlying structure.  A graph seems appropriate, and the [igraph](https://igraph.org/r/) package will probably be helpful.

Comment: Lists are trees, but flowcharts can be any graph.